# Can I initialize data map in open function of ScalarFunction in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, blink

I implemented a customized ScalarFunction class, I would like to initialize a hashmap which read data from a database in open() function, but it always stuck over there, so is it a right way to use open() function like this? and how many time the open() function would be invoked, just once or the same times with eval() function?

My sample code as following:

```
public class GenNameUDF extends ScalarFunction {

    @Override
    public void open(FunctionContext context) throws Exception {
        super.open(context);
        CommonClass.map = initMap();//here will read data from db

    }
    
    public String eval(String pubIp) {
         
         return todo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If the amount of data in db is small, you can use broadcast to acess db only once
2. Otherwise, you can build connection in open method, and access db when needed
3. -yt $file is also helpful.